# How to undo CSS change after clicking on another link

Tags: jquery, css

I have 4 links in my navigation and I want to change the CSS after clicking on a link. However, the link does not change back to the original CSS after I click another link. How can I do this?

E.g. I click "About Us", CSS for "About Us" changes, then click "Products", CSS for "Products" changes. How can I make "About Us" return to original CSS?"

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#page1">&nbsp;Home&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page2">&nbsp;About Us&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page3">&nbsp;Products&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page4">&nbsp;Contact Us&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#nav li a").click(function () {
      $(this).css({'color': 'black', 'border-bottom': '3px dotted black', 'background-color': 'yellow'});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of applying the CSS with jQuery, add another class in your stylesheet:

```
nav li a.active {
    color:black;
    border-bottom:3px dotted black;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Then toggle it with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var navLinks = $("#nav li a");
    navLinks.click(function () {
        navLinks.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/bPeAm/